# Named space url resolution

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to get django [namespaced url resolution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces) working, because I want my boss and his bosses to be able to see the templates and comment on them from an app that just stuffs fake data and doesn't actually do anything, while I use the same templates in developing the live code in a different app.  So if you go to `http://localhost:8000/template_test/base` you see the base.html template with the fake data, and if you go to `http://localhost:8000/uar/base` you see the base.html with the (hopefully) real data.  As an added complication, there is a link on the page that should go to uar.html with either the fake data or the real data depending on whether you've gone to the /template_test/base url or the /uar/base url.

So here's the appropriate part of the template:

```
<li>
  <a href="{% url 'uar:uar' %}">User Access Review</a>
</li>
```

And here is the appropriate part of my project/urls.py

```
url(r'^template_test/', include(template_test.urls,
    namespace="uar", app_name="template_test")),

url(r'^uar/', include(uar.urls, namespace="uar", app_name="uar")),
```

And in template_test/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^base$', template_test.views.base, name="base"),
  url(r'^uar$', template_test.views.uar_missing, name="uar"),
```

And in uar/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^base$', uar.views.base, name="base"),
  url(r'^uar$', uar.views.uar_missing, name="uar"),
```

template_test/views.py

```
def base(request):
    return render(request, "base.html", {"full_name": "Fake User"},
            current_app="template_test")
```

and uar/views.py

```
def base(request):
    return render(request, "base.html", {"full_name": "Paul Tomblin"},
            current_app="uar")

def uar_missing(request):
    return render(request, "uar.html", {}, current_app="uar")
```

But in spite of the fact that I'm providing an app context to the template, when base.html is rendered in either context, the `{% url 'uar:uar' %}` in the template ends up being `/template_test/uar/` in both contexts (the {{full_name}} has the appropriate values, either "Fake User" or "Paul Tomblin" respectively).  What do I have to change to make that link use the current app context?

**Additional Information**  The application context isn't working with reverse:

```
python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse('uar:uar')
'/template_test/uar'
>>> reverse('uar:uar', current_app='uar')
'/template_test/uar'
>>> reverse('uar:uar', current_app='template_test')
'/template_test/uar'
>>> reverse('uar:uar', current_app='txx')
'/template_test/uar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Evidently I was confusing "namespace" and "app_name".  My project/urls.py now looks like:

```
   url(r'^template_test/',
        include(build_urls(template_test.views, 'template_test'),
        namespace="template_test", app_name="uar")),

    url(r'^uar/',
        include(build_urls(uar.views, 'uar'),
        namespace="uar", app_name="uar")),
```

Note: I've switched around namespace and app_name.

The template_test/views.py has

```
def base(request):
    return render(request, "base.html", {"full_name": "Fake User"},
            current_app="template_test")
```

and uar/views.py has

```
def base(request):
    return render(request, "base.html", {"full_name": "Paul Tomblin"})
```

Note: I'm not passing in current_app in the uar/views.py any more.

As an added bonus, I also discovered that when I'm using a redirect, I need to do a "reverse" with the correct current_app.